# Plotly-Dash line chart: custom color not working properly

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a plot in which I want to have different color for different columns based on some logic.

```
col_dict = get_color_map(df.columns)
fig = px.line(data_frame=df, x=df.index, y=df.columns, color_discrete_map=col_dict)
```

The *get_color_map* function returns a dict with column names as keys as string "hsv(h, s, v)" as value.

The legends and hover data color are correct but the lines itself are just all white. I want the color of the lines to match the legend.
[image]

Note: I tried using the *color_discrete_sequence* parameter as will, I got the same result only.

Comment: Hi, can you try this: `fig = px.line(data_frame=df, x=df.index, y=df.columns, color=col_dict,color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet)`

Comment: Hi @hoatran I tried the your solution, and I got the following error : "ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `color` is 20, whereas the length of previously-processed arguments ['time', 'C36700', 'C36800', 'C36900', 'C37000', 'C37100', 'C36600', 'C36500', 'C36400', 'C36300', 'C36200', 'P36700', 'P36800', 'P36900', 'P37000', 'P37100', 'P36600', 'P36500', 'P36400', 'P36300', 'P36200'] is 375"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think plotly express does not provide custom color map without specifying the color parameter, which in data frame case should be a column itself. [Ref](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/an-intro-to-customizing-charts-in-plotly-express-e3c473740f66)

So in this case where each column by itself should have different color without a hue column, it is best to use the plotly graph_object library.

The following code works:

```
fig = go.Figure()
for col in df.columns:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df[col], name=col, mode='lines', line=dict(color=col_dict[col])))
```

Comment: For me, I'm providing the color arg, color_discrete_map, and category_orders but it's still not working. It works if all values are numbers, but as soon as I add a longer string that's not a number, it doesn't work. I figured out the issue though. The values provided to color_discrete_map must exactly match those in the supplied data. In my case, I had a mismatch between numeric and string data types.